# Send checkbox status data to email

Tags: android, email, android-intent, checkbox

I simply want to save in an email the true/false status of a check box.  I am new and teaching myself as I go so i apologize. Thank you in advance!!  Here is what i have:

```
    public class eActivity extends Activity {

    private CheckBox check1;

    ///onCreate

    check1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check1);

    ///Email Intent

    email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
    ////What do i put here to get the state of the checkbox true/false?////
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I needed:

```
    email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,

    ///All I have to put here is:
    check1.isChecked()
```

And it works perfect now, thankyou!